# airflow on kubernetes: how to load dag files from local filesystem?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, bitnami

i want to install airflow for my k8s cluster. I tried to use the bitnami repo but i want to know how to load dag files from my local filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution we implement is

- Keep the dags,sqls,utils,plugins in github(or any other repo)
- If you are using k8s using AWS then Use EFS(shared file system).
- you can check https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/tree/master/aws/efs
- Then you need to mount the efs volume for your scheduler and webserver as readonly option.

This is our preferred approach.

Comment: i´m working in local servers ( with Ubuntu as an OS ), i created a repo in github and added it in the  Git section of the values.yaml then i installed the chart using helm. but the pods are not running

Comment: i was using an incorrect link of git repo, now it works fine; thank you

Comment: ok. does my answer help you ? Please let me know.

Comment: please i wanted to know how to connect postgresql with airflow. i installed airflow using bitnami repo, it comes with postgresql. Now i need to get some data and put them in postgresql using airflow.

Comment: @Elpis I did not understand your question . You want to load data to postgres or postgres is your source. Please clarify further.  Check if this helps. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/operators/postgres_operator_howto_guide.html

Comment: this is what i needed https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/operators/postgres_operator_howto_guide.html, thank you

Comment: Great.. Glad I was of help.